# Replacement of parameters in seo url with htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, friendly-url

My url:

> x.com/ara?il=istanbul&ilce=avcilar&marka=opel&model=corsa

> x.com/rent/istanbul-avcilar-opel-corsa

In htaccess:

```
RewriteRule ^rent/([0-9a-zA-Z-_]+)-([0-9a-zA-Z-_]+)-([0-9a-zA-Z-_]+)-([0-9a-zA-Z-_]+)$ ara.php?il=$1&ilce=$2&marka=$3&model=$4 [L,QSA]
```

it works if all parameters exist. But does not work if there is no **ilce** or **model** parameter in the url.

So I want it to work also in these situations

```
x.com/ara?il=istanbul&marka=opel&model=corsa 
x.com/rent/istanbul-opel-corsa

x.com/ara?il=istanbul&marka=opel 
x.com/rent/istanbul-opel

x.com/ara?il=istanbul&ilce=avcilar&marka=opel 
x.com/rent/istanbul-avcilar-opel
```

How should htaccess be for this?

Comment: Could you please provide URL which will be served by `x.com/ara?il=istanbul&marka=opel&model=corsa` AND URL which will be served by `x.com/ara?il=istanbul&ilce=avcilar&marka=opel` too. That will give us better understanding of your question, thank you.

Comment: Sorry. I edited added

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With your shown samples, could you please try following. Please make sure to clear your browser cache before testing your URLs.

```
RewriteEngine ON
##Rule for rewrite of (x.com/rent/istanbul-opel-corsa) TO (x.com/ara?il=istanbul&marka=opel&model=corsa) url.
RewriteRule ^rent/(istanbul)-(opel)-(corsa)/?$ ara?il=$1&marka=$2&model=$3 [NC,L]

##Rule for rewrite of (x.com/rent/istanbul-opel) TO (x.com/ara?il=istanbul&marka=opel) url.
RewriteRule ^rent/(istanbul)-(opel)/?$ ara?il=$1&marka=$2 [NC,L]

##Rule for rewrite of (x.com/rent/istanbul-avcilar-opel) TO (x.com/ara?il=istanbul&ilce=avcilar&marka=opel) url.
RewriteRule ^rent/(istanbul)-(avcilar)-(opel)/?$ ara?il=$1&marka=$2&model=$3 [NC,L]
```

---

---

For Generic rule sets try following:

```
RewriteEngine ON
##Rule for rewrite of (x.com/rent/istanbul-opel-corsa) TO (x.com/ara?il=istanbul&marka=opel&model=corsa) url.
RewriteRule ^rent/([^-]*)-([^-]*)-(.*)/?$ ara?il=$1&marka=$2&model=$3 [NC,L]

##Rule for rewrite of (x.com/rent/istanbul-opel) TO (x.com/ara?il=istanbul&marka=opel) url.
RewriteRule ^rent/([^-]*)-([^-]*)/?$ ara?il=$1&marka=$2 [NC,L]
```